# Can't connect to Cassandra when i'm trying to edit cassandra.yaml

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Every time i'm trying to edit the `cassandra.yaml` file, I can't connect to Cassandra with `cqlsh`, even if I don't modify the file.

I'm getting the following error :

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

The parameters for `rpc_address` and `listen_address` are good, even for the port.

I really need help for this, thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure how changing the config file would cause a one-time-problem to connect to C* with cqlsh? You should always be able to connect with cqlsh or not at all. Or do I misunderstand your question?

Comment: For a project, i have to import a lot of data on my cassandra data base( 8 millions). I've a problem during the copy so i modify a line in the file and restart Cassandra. Than cassandra didnt Work so i cancel the change (sorry for my english). Even after this, it didnt work. Whasnt the first time that append.

Comment: What was the change you made in the cassandra.yaml?

Comment: write_request_timeout_in_ms = 2000 to write_request_timeout_in_ms = 20000 and  after i go back

Comment: @AlexandreS. I am facing the same problem. Were you able to find any solution?

Comment: I didnt find a really good solution. Atleast, sometimes, delete commitlog in /var/lib works

Answer (score 0):

Before going query on cassandra setup or export the environment variable of cqlsh.

You have to export HOST AND PORT in environment like:

> export CQLSH_HOST="hostname/ip_address"
>
> export CQLSH_PORT="cassandra_port"

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting like this:

> cqlsh IP_ADDRESS_HERE -u cassandra